# TSQL - Locating first occurrence of value in a string

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, string-math

I need to run a simple select statement for a column called AddrZip to show all records that contain  '1/2 ' after the first space in the column. In Access 2007 it would be:
 `**Left([Names],InStr(1,[Names]," ")-1)`, but can't find out how to do it in SQL 2005. All help will be appreciated.

Comment: substitute InStr(x, y, z) with charindex(x, y, z) and you are done.

Comment: Sue, did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

First, look for records with a `' '`:

`CHARINDEX(' ', [AddrZip]) > 0`

Then look for records with a `'1/2'` occurring *after* the `' '`

`CHARINDEX('1/2', [AddrZip], CHARINDEX(' ', [AddrZip])) > 0`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    *
          FROM      [Addresses]
          WHERE     CHARINDEX(' ', [AddrZip]) > 0
        ) x
WHERE   CHARINDEX('1/2', [x].[AddrZip], CHARINDEX(' ', [AddrZip])) > 0
```

This "simplified" version *may* work:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [Addresses]
WHERE   CHARINDEX(' ', [AddrZip]) > 0
        AND CHARINDEX('1/2', [x].[AddrZip], CHARINDEX(' ', [AddrZip])) > 0
```

If you want to find occurrences of `'1/2'` that are  **immediately preceded** by a `' '` where the `' '` is the very first space in the string, then use the following code:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [Addresses]
WHERE   CHARINDEX(' ', [AddrZip]) > 0
        AND CHARINDEX(' ', [AddrZip]) = CHARINDEX(' 1/2', [x].[AddrZip])
```

---

Avoid `LIKE` operators if at all possible. They are notoriously slow.

Comment: Just a thought. This matches even strings 'sss 11/2' which is not what OP wants

Comment: @Sachin, why not? I see a '1/2' and a ' ' before it? What that not the OP's specifications? The OP did not say that the '1/2' needed to **immediately** follow the ' '.

Comment: Yes, you naybe right. There is no mention of 1/2 following a space immediately. I have assumed the 1/2 follows space thing. Lets see what OP really wants. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
select * from table where addrZip like '%\ 1/2%' escape '\'
```